# Remove directory in URL [HTACCESS]

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using this in my .htaccess file...

```
Redirect /index.html http://jurrasicgames.net/JurrasicGamesDatFile/Index.html
Redirect /VIP.html http://jurrasicgames.net/JurrasicGamesDatFile/VIP.html
Redirect /sg.html http://jurrasicgames.net/Soon.SHMTL
Redirect /kitpvp.html http://jurrasicgames.net/JurrasicGamesDatFile/kitpvp.html
```

I want http://jurrasicgames.net/JurrasicGamesDatFile/kitpvp.html to look like http://jurrasicgames.net/KitPVP is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Redirect` directive as it does a full redirect. Use internal rewrite instead.

.htaccess to be used in site root ( a level above `JurrasicGamesDatFile` )

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ JurrasicGamesDatFile/Index.html [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^VIP\.html$ JurrasicGamesDatFile/VIP.html [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^sg\.html$ Soon.SHMTL [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^kitpvp\.html$ JurrasicGamesDatFile/kitpvp.html [L,NC]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing it.

Comment: It isn't re directing to my pages anymore.

Comment: Is it showing 404 to you? What URL are you entering in browser?